# Mysql permission errors with 'load data'

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile, mysql-error-1045

I am running into a permission error when trying to load data from a flat file database dump into a new table. I know that the schema of the file and my table is the same and I tried tweaking the permissions. What else should I try?

```
mysql> load data infile 'myfile.txt' into table mytable fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"';
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'%' 

grant all on mytable.* to 'user'@'%
```

Comment: See also [What file and directory permissions are required for MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3971541) (try changing `LOAD DATA INFILE 'myfile.txt'` to `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myfile.txt'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [access denied for load data infile in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221335/access-denied-for-load-data-infile-in-mysql)

Comment: @DannyBeckett solution with 'LOCAL' might not be available for all mysql versions. For instance , for '5.7.34-log' won't work.

Comment: Correcting myself, The above solution with 'LOCAL' might require an additional set of the property 'allowLoadLocalInfile' to 'TRUE'.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[Here's a thread](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?30,12298,12313#msg-12313) on the MySQL forums that discusses exactly this.

Here's the answer, posted by Ken Tassell

> Problem resolved using the command below:

```
grant file on *.* to kentest@localhost identified by 'kentest1';
```

Answer (score 7):

You might have MySQL privileges on the destination table, but you also need the `FILE` privilege to execute `LOAD DATA`, and of course the MySQL Server process needs operating-system privileges to the data file too.

Comment: Thank you for the description of the problem. Helped me!