# access denied for load data infile in MySQL

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile, mysql-error-1045

I use MySQL queries all the time in PHP, but when I try

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE
```

I get the following error

> #1045 - Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Does anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 243):

I just ran into this issue as well. I had to add **`LOCAL`** to my SQL statement.

For example, this gives the permission problem:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '{$file}' INTO TABLE {$table}
```

Add **`LOCAL`** to your statement and the permissions issue should go away. Like so:

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{$file}' INTO TABLE {$table}
```

Comment: This does a different thing. It uploads your file to the server in a temporary directory. This is necessary sometimes, but if the infile is on the MySQL server already, you're just making redundant work.

Comment: yep this did the trick for me, I was forwarding the database server port over ssh and I guess it was looking for the file on the remote database server without the LOCAL part

Comment: @jeremysawesome for me this produces the following error: Error Code: 1148 The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version. I tried some answers for this problem such as modifying the mysql file to local-infile=1 and that failed as well.

Comment: an update of mySQL to 6.2.5 solved this problem for me

Comment: you may also have to call mysql with the `--local-infile` option.

Comment: I wish for two things: (a) that Google found this question when I was looking for an answer, and (b) that MySQL supplied a more specific error message for this, as it is insanely annoying to waste half a day on something so simple...

Comment: this did the trick to me! once my server and mysql are on different machines  the LOCAL statement to upload the file to mysql server works like a charm! thanks

Comment: Important: If file gets uploaded to server with `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` and there are constrains  conflicts on insert, then it won't return any error/exception and will execute and returns true.

Comment: and also use absolute path for file : /home/[currentuser]/filename

Comment: `ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version`

Answer (score 40):

I had this problem.  I searched around and did not find a satisfactory answer.  I summarise below the results of my searches.

The access denied error could mean that:

- 'user'@'localhost' does not have the FILE privilege (`GRANT FILE on *.* to user@'localhost'`); or,
- the file you are trying to load does not exist on the machine running mysql server (if using LOAD DATA INFILE); or,
- the file you are trying to load does not exist on your local machine (if using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE); or,
- the file you are trying to load is not world readable (you need the file *and* all parent directories to be world-readable: chmod 755 directory; and, chmod 744 file.dat)

Comment: +1: This worked for me: _the file you are trying to load is not world readable (you need the file and all parent directories to be world-readable: chmod 755 directory; and, chmod 744 file.dat)_. I hadn't changed permissions on all my directories

Comment: User Tatiana points out that you can't grant the FILE privilege per database, only for the whole server. The grant command would be "GRANT FILE on *.* to user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password');"

Comment: @JAL I think you mean "GRANT FILE ON \*.\* to user ..." -- probably the asterisk characters were stripped

Comment: as @Eugene M said this gives error [Incorrect usage of DB GRANT and GLOBAL PRIVILEGES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552206/grant-file-on-just-one-database)

Answer (score 21):

Try using this command:

```
load data local infile 'home/data.txt' into table customer;
```

This should work. It worked in my case.

Comment: `ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version`

Comment: @Stewart, please remove 'local' from the above command. Later mysql versions do not seem to support this flag when global variable 'local_infile' variable is set to 'ON' (as below).

The command will therefore, be;
mysql> load data infile 'home/data.txt' into table customer;

+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| local_infile  | ON    |
+---------------+-------+

Comment: @KamranHyder  Sounds like you have a good answer to me. Why not add it as a full answer?

Answer (score 11):

Ensure your MySQL user has the FILE privilege granted.

If you are on shared web hosting, there is a chance this is blocked by your hosting provider.

Comment: On a shared web hosting: would it be helpful to use "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE"?

Answer (score 7):

If you are trying this on MySQL Workbench,

Go to connections -> edit connection -> select advanced tab

and add `OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1` in the 'Others' text field.

Now restart the connection and try.

[image]

Comment: love the answer since it has the screenshot as well as specifies restarting

Answer (score 4):

I found easy one if you are using command line

Login as`mysql -u[username] -p[password] --local-infile`

then `SET GLOBAL local_infile = 1;`

select your database by `use [db_name]`

and finally `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\shant\\Downloads\\data-1573708892247.csv' INTO TABLE visitors_final_test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','LINES TERMINATED BY '\r \n' IGNORE 1 LINES;`

Comment: Adding of --local-inline helped me. However, local_infile global variable was already set to ON in my case. I think users better to figure out first what value they have written in this variable before modifying it.

Comment: For RDS users => Adding the --local-infile helped me on RDS, however `SET GLOBAL local_infile = 1;` doesn't seem to work in RDS, but anyway without that the `--local-infile` did the trick

Answer (score 3):

The string from Lyon gave me a very good tip: On Windows, we need to use slahes and not backslashes. This code works for me:

```
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile(tableName, ".csv");
    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(data, tempFile);

    JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    String path = tempFile.getAbsolutePath().replace('\\', '/');
    int rows = template.update(MessageFormat
            .format("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ''{0}'' INTO TABLE {1} FIELDS TERMINATED BY '',''",
                    path, tableName));
    logger.info("imported {} rows into {}", rows, tableName);

    tempFile.delete();
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, and solve it by folowing those steps :

- activate load_infile variable
- grand file permission to my custom mysql user
- deactivate secure_file_priv variable (my file was uploaded by the webserver to the /tmp folder which is of course not the secured directory of myslq /var/lib/mysql-file)

For this 3rd point, you can refer to : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv

BR,

AD

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me as well and despite having followed all the steps described by Yamir in his post I couldn't make it work.

The file was in /tmp/test.csv with 777 permissions. The MySQL user had file permissions, LOCAL option was not allowed by my MySQL version, so I was stuck.

Finally I was able to solve the problem by running:

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql /tmp/test.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered loading MySQL tables can be fast and painless (I was using python / Django model manager scripts):

1) create table with all columns VARCHAR(n) NULL e.g.:

`mysql> CREATE TABLE cw_well2( api VARCHAR(10) NULL,api_county VARCHAR(3) NULL);`

2) remove headers (first line) from csv, then load (if you forget the LOCAL, you’ll get “#1045 - Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)”):

`mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/home/magula6/cogswatch2/well2.csv" INTO TABLE cw_well2 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> ;
Query OK, 119426 rows affected, 19962 warnings  (3.41 sec)`

3) alter columns:

`mysql> ALTER TABLE cw_well2 CHANGE spud_date spud_date DATE;`

`mysql> ALTER TABLE cw_well2 CHANGE latitude latitude FLOAT;`

voilà!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to insert data from CSV to MYSQL DB using python.
You can try the below method to load data from CSV to Database.

1. Make a connection with the Database using pymysql or MySQL.connector any library you want in python.
2. Make Sure you are able to use the in-line while connecting for that while providing host, user, and password try to add local_inline=True.
3. 

> > Skipping to load data part.
> >  `sql = f'''LOAD DATA LOCAL infile "filename.csv" INTO TABLE schema.tablename FILED TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'''' Note: If you have column names in CSV, use IGNORE ROW 1 LINES. The execute the sql by: cursor.execute(sql) conn.commit() conn.close()`

Answer (score -6):

It probably means that the password you supplied for `'user'@'localhost'` is incorrect.

Comment: I don't think so.  I can do other queries with the same password.