# What file and directory permissions are required for MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE?

Tags: mysql, permissions, load-data-infile

I have a script that is trying to load some data into MySQL with `LOAD DATA INFILE`. For some reason, it works if the file is in the `/tmp` directory, but not if the file is in another directory with identical permissions. I can't find any way to get MySQL to import data from outside the `/tmp` directory, or the database directory, but I can't find anything in the manual that explains why this would be the case.

The situation:

```
$ ls -l /
...
drwxrwxrwt  21 root root  4096 2010-10-19 20:02 tmp
drwxrwxrwt   2 root root  4096 2010-10-19 20:14 tmp2

$ ls -l /tmp/data.csv 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 timm timm 415431 2010-10-19 20:02 /tmp/data.csv

$ ls -l /tmp2/data.csv 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 timm timm 415431 2010-10-19 20:14 /tmp2/data.csv
```

AFAICT these are identical in the important respects. However, if at the MySQL command line I do:

```
> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp2/data.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE ports
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY ' ';
ERROR 29 (HY000): File '/tmp2/data.csv' not found (Errcode: 13)

> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/data.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE ports 
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY ' ';
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.04 sec)
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

I gather from forum postings that errno 13 indicates a permission problem. It seems that `/tmp` is treated specially by MySQL, but why? The closest I can come is a line in the manual saying:

> For security reasons, when reading text files located on the server, the files must either reside in the database directory or be readable by all.

`/tmp` isn't in the database directory, but maybe it gets treated as if it is. So how should I set things up in order for it to read files outside of `/tmp`?

Comment: What happens if you `export TMPDIR=/tmp2` before running `mysql`?

Comment: I don't know how to get MySQL to use variables from my environment, but if I change the value of `tmpdir` in the my.cnf it doesn't affect the behaviour (tmp2 still fails, even though it's now the temp directory)

Comment: The temp dir saved my day using LOAD DATA INFILE

Answer (score 17):

```
mysqlimport --local <database> <infile>
```

OR

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE... should fix the issue.
```

Comment: +1 without local it is resolved in the context of the server process - so you can load data from client and from server

Answer (score 3):

Errcode 13 means missing permissions (in contrast to Errcode 2, which means the file does not exist). MySQL needs the file to be readable by anyone. THe permissions of your files are fine.

We once had the same issue on a CentOS server and it was caused by **AppArmor** which forbid the MySQL application to access files not being listed in a whitelist in /etc/ap­par­mor.d/usr.​sbin.​mysqld. Maybe you have some kind of security suit which causes a similar behavior?

As mentioned by others, using LOAD DATA INFILE **LOCAL** can be a workaround.

Comment: Was trying to do exactly the same thing, and editing AppArmor's whitelist file for mysql solved this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered a similar problem (unable to read a file in `/tmp`) and adding `LOCAL` after `LOAD DATA INFILE` fixed the problem.

This [Launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-dfsg-5.0/+bug/244406) might have some explanations as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Errno 13 might be due to SELinux in case you are using a Linux server distro (for example, RedHat Enterprise Linux or CentOS). Check 'audit.log' to see if SELinux is complaining about your `/tmp2` path. You can then add your path via `semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t "/tmp2(/.*)?"` and run `restorecon -R /tmp2`.

However, the solution might be much simpler and I would have replied directly under your question (instead of providing an answer), if I only knew how..

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 Desktop edition, with MySQL installed from Ubuntu packages.

Comment: Okay, so SELinux is not the problem there. Have you tried 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ...'? Does it give you the same result?