# How to allow mysql(mariadb) to read files from /tmp - Fedora 30

Tags: mysql, mariadb, fedora

I've written a program receives data from a socket, formats the data to  CSV format, then dumps the data to a file; '/tmp/test_csv.csv'.

Next, I execute the following in mysql:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test_csv.csv'
INTO TABLE flow_data
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

This statement outputs the following error:

```
Can't get stat of '/tmp/test_csv.csv' (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
```

From what I understand, mysql doesn't have access to read from /tmp, which makes perfect sense.

The solution i'm looking for is to give mysql access to read from /tmp, whilst retaining its inability to write there (the latter is optional).

I need to dump the csv file to /tmp (or any other RAMdisk style directory) because of it's size, so dumping the file to the mysql database directory isn't a valid solution. The quantity of data i'm working with would cause my hard disk to get heavily contended (by both the file, and mysql) if it wasn't stored in-memory.

The only solution I have found/tried involves changing perms with semanage. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3971632/1449160
However, I had no luck with it.

I've also seen there is a workaround, by using the keyword LOCAL. However, i'm uncertain of the performance implications of this solution and would much rather let mysql read the file directly - or at least test to see if it matters.

OS: Fedora 30

```
mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.12-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)
```

*EDIT
Both the file (/tmp/test_csv.csv) and the sql server are in the same machine. I know 'LOAD DATA LOCAl INFILE' would also work, but i'm trying to get mysql to read the file directly

Comment: What is the owner of the file ? File permissions must be wrong. `mysql` user must have read access to the file load it.

Comment: ```sudo chown mysql test_csv.csv```
Still no luck. Same error

Comment: What about /tmp permissions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably caused by the fact that nowadays most daemons have a **private** TMPFS (including mysqld). In order to allow mysql to access `/tmp`, you need to change its daemon configuration like so:

```sh
export SYSTEMD_EDITOR=vim #Change the editor to the one you prefer
sudo -E systemctl edit --full mysqld.service
# Search for "PrivateTmp" and change it to "false", then save the file
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart mysqld.service
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` if the file is on the machine's connected to the database and not on the server itself as `LOAD DATA INFILE` will look on the mysql server's filesystem.

Comment: I should have been more clear, the file is on the same server as the mysql server.