# Access denied for user with "load infile" using mysql

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I have a text file which I want to load into a MySQL database.

When I execute the command:

```
load data infile '/saurabh/chk1.txt'
   into table chk1 fields terminated by '\t' lines terminated by '\n';
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'saurabh'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Since I thought this was a permissioning problem, I used `show grants` command,

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'saurabh'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*40639DEF' 

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `saurabh`.* TO 'saurabh'@'localhost' .
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I cleaned up your question a bit and indented your code and error messages by 4 spaces so that they render properly - please see [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.

Answer (score 0):

See this post [Mysql permission errors with 'load data'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014724/mysql-permission-errors-with-load-data)

Try: `grant file on *.* to saurabh@localhost identified by 'saurabh'`

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the file you want to load in the Public directory (`C:\Users\Public`) and after that try to load it again. That is what fixed the problem for me.